# How to correctly annotate a QuerySet with the number of elements in a Many2Many relation?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm modelling amateur soccer Games where two teams of players play against each other.
I'm trying to **annotate the QuerySet with the number of players in each team** to then identify games with different number of players in each team.

The models I have are pretty straight forward:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    nickname = models.CharField(...)

class Team(models.Model):
    players = models.ManyToManyField(Player)

class Game(modeos.Model):
    team1 = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    team2 = models.ForeignKey(Team)
```

When I go to the shell (`python manage shell`) and execute the following command to get the number of players of the teams in each match **I got the expected results**:

```
[(game.team1.players.count(), game.team2.players.count()) for game in Game.objects.all()]
```

```
[(7, 7), (7, 10), (7, 7), (7, 7), (7, 7)]
```

However, when I try to do the same with `annotations`:

```
Game.objects.annotate(t1c=Count('team1__players'), t2c=Count('team2__players')).values('t1c','t2c')
```

**I got incorrect results**:

```
<QuerySet [{'t1c': 49, 't2c': 49}, {'t1c': 70, 't2c': 70}, {'t1c': 49, 't2c': 49}, {'t1c': 49, 't2c': 49}, {'t1c': 49, 't2c': 49}]>
```

Which are the multiplication of both values.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/aggregation/#combining-multiple-aggregations)

> Combining multiple aggregations with annotate() will [yield the wrong
> results](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10060) because joins are used instead of subqueries
>
> For most aggregates, there is no way to avoid this problem, however,
> the Count aggregate has a **`distinct`** parameter that may help

```
Game.objects.annotate(
        t1c=Count('team1__players', distinct=True),
        t2c=Count('team2__players', distinct=True)
    ).values('t1c','t2c')
```

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer noted, the django docs point out that the result is incorrect because joins are used instead of subqueries. The ORM does provide a way to use subqueries instead, which is useful when `distinct=True` doesn't fix your problem (and in my experience, more performant than joins with distinct=True).

First, your model definition for `Game` is not correct. ForeignKey has to have `on_delete` defined, and when you have two ForeignKeys to the same model you have to define a related_name for at least one of them or you will get a conflict. So, I am using this as the definition of the Game model

```
class Game(models.Model):
    played = models.DateField()
    team1 = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name='team1_game')
    team2 = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name='team2_game')
```

To do your Count aggregation using a subquery:

```
t1c_count_query = Player.objects.filter(
    team__id=OuterRef('team1_id')
).values(
    'team__team1_game__id'  # Required for proper group by in the subquery
).annotate(
    player_count=Count('id')
).values(
    'player_count'  # Required to select only a single value in a subquery
)

Game.objects.annotate(t1c=Subquery(t1c_count_query))
```

And you can do the same for t2c and use them in the same query and everything works.

This is made easier by the [django-sql-utils](https://pypi.org/project/django-sql-utils/) app. After you `pip install django-sql-utils`

```
from sql_util.utils import SubqueryCount

Game.objects.annotate(
    t1c=SubqueryCount('team1__players'),
    t2c=SubqueryCount('team2__players')
).values('t1c', 't2c')
```

Comment: This was incredibly helpful to solve a quite complicated bug. Thank you!